# NodeJS - Convert Array of Objects into Object of Objects

Tags: node.js, dictionary

I'm trying to convert this data - Array of Objects

```
const data = [
  {
    userid: 100,
    text: 'yea',
    new: true,
    datetime: 2018-09-04T20:21:17.000Z
  },
  {
    userid: 101,
    text: 'its heading to another new year... wow the time flies...',
    new: true,
    datetime: 2018-09-03T21:51:27.000Z
  },
  {
    userid: 102,
    text: 'wish you the same ...thanks',
    new: true,
    datetime: 2018-01-12T01:36:28.000Z
  }
]
```

Into the following Structure - Object of Objects

```
{
    100: {
        userid: 100,
        text: 'yea',
        new: true,
        datetime: 2018-09-04T20:21:17.000Z
    },
    101: {
        userid: 101,
        text: 'its heading to another new year... wow the time flies...',
        new: true,
        datetime: 2018-09-03T21:51:27.000Z
      },
     102: {
        userid: 102,
        text: 'wish you the same ...thanks',
        new: true,
        datetime: 2018-01-12T01:36:28.000Z
      }
}
```

I've tried

```
messages.map((data) => ({[Math.round(new Date(data.datetime).getTime() / 1000)]: data}))
```

and I get the structure but map returns an array and I need an object. Been playing with reduce() - no luck yet..

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After mapping, use `Object.fromEntries` to turn each sub-array of `[key, value]`s into a property on the resulting object:

```js
const data = [
  {
    userid: 100,
    text: 'yea',
    new: true,
    datetime: `2018-09-04T20:21:17.000Z`
  },
  {
    userid: 101,
    text: 'its heading to another new year... wow the time flies...',
    new: true,
    datetime: `2018-09-03T21:51:27.000Z`
  },
  {
    userid: 102,
    text: 'wish you the same ...thanks',
    new: true,
    datetime: `2018-01-12T01:36:28.000Z`
  }
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(obj => [obj.userid, obj])
);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```js
const data = [
    {
        userid: 100,
        text: 'yea',
        new: true,
        datetime: `2018-09-04T20:21:17.000Z`
    },
    {
        userid: 101,
        text: 'its heading to another new year... wow the time flies...',
        new: true,
        datetime: `2018-09-03T21:51:27.000Z`
    },
    {
        userid: 102,
        text: 'wish you the same ...thanks',
        new: true,
        datetime: `2018-01-12T01:36:28.000Z`
    }];

    const result = {};

    data.map((a) => {
      result[a.userid] = a;
      return a;
    });

    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with reduce

```js
const data = [
    {
        userid: 100,
        text: 'yea',
        new: true,
        datetime: `2018-09-04T20:21:17.000Z`
    },
    {
        userid: 101,
        text: 'its heading to another new year... wow the time flies...',
        new: true,
        datetime: `2018-09-03T21:51:27.000Z`
    },
    {
        userid: 102,
        text: 'wish you the same ...thanks',
        new: true,
        datetime: `2018-01-12T01:36:28.000Z`
    }];

const a = data.reduce((acc, i) => ({...acc,[i.userid]:i}), {})
console.log(a);
```